# How to configure Internet/Network connection

Tags: 11.04, drivers, networking, acer, internet-connection

I am unable to connect to the internet. I attached a LAN wire but i really cant understand the issue behind it. I need appropriate network drivers for acer aspire 5742. Please help

Comment: please attach the output of lspci and ifconfig by editing your initial posting! Also add information on your Network setup (do you use a router, DHCP, etc)?

Answer (score 1):

I think I saw a rather extensive HowTo on that on the UBUNTU forums. Go check there.

[Ubuntu HowTo Forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=100)

Regards, Josh